# Given the coordinates of a box, how can I find the coordinates of a box that is X% bigger than the original box

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

So I'm given a box (the inner box in the picture) and I need to figure out the coordinates of the end points of the outer box given only the coordinates of the inner box.

So far I've gotten the length and width of the original box and cut it in half so I could use the Pythagorean theorem to get the length of the line from the center point of the original box to one of the corners. For this example I extended the hypotenuse twice as far and drew the box expanded at that size.

Given the variables I have, what formula can I use to determine the coordinates of this outer box? For the actual application of this the amount the original box expands will be anywhere from 10-100% and the box will not always be a square, but will always be a rectangle. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Just so I have this straight, you extended the hypotenuse by its length, drew another square, and now you want to determine the coordinates of the vertices of this new square?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Extend the other leg of the triangle, and note that you have another isosceles right triangle.  Use this to compute the length $\ell$ of the legs of the new triangle.  Then, if the center of the original square is $(x_0,y_0)$, the four vertices of the new square will be $(x_0\pm\ell,y_0\pm\ell)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a square box be centered in $(x_0,y_0)$ with length $l$. Another box which is $X\%$ bigger in size (length), has its vertices on the following 4 points:$$(x_0+X\%{l\over 2},y_0+X\%{l\over 2})\\(x_0-X\%{l\over 2},y_0+X\%{l\over 2})\\(x_0+X\%{l\over 2},y_0-X\%{l\over 2})\\(x_0-X\%{l\over 2},y_0-X\%{l\over 2})$$

Comment: And notice that you don't need to know the length of the diagonal. You just need to consider the horizontal and vertical sides of the triangle.